# Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.IconCompatParcelizer

Tags: android

I am a trying to learn Android studio at home and today i was learning `ocr` and followed a clip and at the end in the clip it worked but not for me i got the following **error:**

> Error: Program type already present: 
>       android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.IconCompatParcelizer

my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.imagetotextmobileload"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


    //image crop library
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'

    //image to text google library
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2'
 }
```

my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
                app:cardElevation="3dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="5dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Result"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <!--The scanned text from image will display here-->
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/resultEt"
                        android:hint="Click + button to insert Image"
                        android:autoLink="all"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
                app:cardElevation="3dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="5dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Image Preview"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <!--The image taken will be displayed here-->
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageIv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:maxHeight="250dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my MainActivity.java file

```
package com.example.android.imagetotextmobileload;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.drm.DrmStore;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.Frame;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextBlock;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextRecognizer;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText mResultEt;
    ImageView mPreviewIv;

    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    private static final int STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 400;
    private static final int IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE = 1000;
    private static final int IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE = 1001;

    String cameraPermission[];
    String storagePermission[];

    Uri image_uri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mResultEt = findViewById(R.id.resultEt);
        mPreviewIv = findViewById(R.id.imageIv);

        //camera permission
        cameraPermission = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        //storage permission
        storagePermission = new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
    }

    //actionbar menu

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //inflate menu
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    //handle actionbar item clicks
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.addImage){
            showImageImportDialog();
        }
        if (id == R.id.settings){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void showImageImportDialog() {
        //items to display in dialog
        String[] items = {" Camera", " Gallery"};
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        //set title
        dialog.setTitle("Select Image");
        dialog.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (which == 0){
                    //camera option clicked
                    /*for OS marshmallow and above we need to ask runtime permission for camera and storage*/
                    if (!checkCameraPermission()){
                        //camera permission not allowed, request it
                        requestCameraPermission();
                    }
                    else {
                        //permission allowed, take picture
                        pickCamera();
                    }
                }
                if (which == 1){
                    //gallery option clicked
                    if (!checkStoragePermission()){
                        //Storage permission not allowed, request it
                        requestStoragePermission();
                    }
                    else {
                        //permission allowed, open picture
                        pickGallery();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        dialog.create().show(); //show dialog
    }

    private void pickGallery() {
        //intent to pick image from gallery
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        //set intent type to image
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE);
    }

    private void pickCamera() {
        //intent to take image from camera, it will also be saved to storage to get high quality image
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "NewPic"); //title of the picture
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Image To Text"); 
//description
        image_uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE);
    }

    private void requestStoragePermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, storagePermission, STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private boolean checkStoragePermission() {
        boolean result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        return result;
    }

    private void requestCameraPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, cameraPermission, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

     private boolean checkCameraPermission() {
        /*Check camera permision and return the result
         *In order to get high quality image we have to save to external 
storage first
         * before inserting to image view that's why storage permission will also be required.*/
        boolean result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        boolean result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        return result && result1;
    }

    //handle permission result
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length >0){
                    boolean cameraAccepted = grantResults[0] ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean writeStorageAccepted = grantResults[0] ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    if (cameraAccepted && writeStorageAccepted){
                        pickCamera();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                break;

            case STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length >0){
                    boolean writeStorageAccepted = grantResults[0] ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    if (writeStorageAccepted){
                        pickGallery();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    //handle image result
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RESULT_OK){
            if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE){
                //got image from gallery now crop it
                CropImage.activity(data.getData())
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON) //enable image guidlines
                    .start(this);
            }
            if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE){
                //got image from camera now crop it
                CropImage.activity(image_uri)
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON) //enable image guidlines
                    .start(this);
            }
        }
        //get cropped image
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
             if (requestCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri resultUri = result.getUri(); //get image uri
                //set image to image view
                mPreviewIv.setImageURI(resultUri);

                //get drawable bitmap for text recognition
                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)mPreviewIv.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();

                TextRecognizer recognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();

                if (!recognizer.isOperational()){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
                    SparseArray<TextBlock> items = recognizer.detect(frame);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    //get text from sb until there is no text
                    for (int i = 0; i<items.size(); i++){
                        TextBlock myItem = items.valueAt(i);
                        sb.append(myItem.getValue());
                        sb.append("\n");
                    }
                    //set text to edit text
                    mResultEt.setText(sb.toString());
                }
            }
            else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE){
                //if there is any error show it.
                Exception error = result.getError();
                Toast.makeText(this, ""+error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was playing around in Android Studio and i migrated to androidX and it is now working

Comment: main thing is app in running but it do not display anything from camera into my imageview